# p-adic diophantine approximation

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Suppose you have a sequence of rational numbers that gives a diophantine approximaion an irrational, what can be said p-adically about this sequence?

I'm interested in the p-adic analoges of these theorems (such as Thue-siegel-roth), but can't find any straightforward resources on the subject. I can't even find what a good diophantine approximation would mean over a p-adic field.

Comment: The $p$-adic theory is quite well developed. See, for example, the paper of D. Ridout "The p-adic generalization of the Thue-Siegel-Roth theorem",
Mathematika 5 1958 40–48. Schlickewei has proved a $p$-adic version of Schmidt's theorem, see "Linearformen mit algebraischen koeffizienten",
Manuscripta Math. 18 (1976), no. 2, 147–185.  

Comment: I'm aware of these particular references listed on the wikipedia page, the problem is I can't find them anywhere.

Comment: If you have access to a library, you could look into interlibrary loan. 

Answer (score 2):

The paper by Schlickewei mentioned in the comment is available here:

http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN365956996_0018&DMDID=DMDLOG_0012

In general, many old mathematical papers can be obtained free of charge via the site

http://www.emani.org/

Often these papers cannot be found by standard search englines.